# detecting the model number of mobile phone (iOS and Android) using users agent

Tags: html

How to detect the model of mobile phone using users agent, is there any way for detecting all information of mobile phone including model?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing mobile phone user agent string , good solution or library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516108/parsing-mobile-phone-user-agent-string-good-solution-or-library)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3540295/5693811  here you get the answer for your question